# Reading ElastiCache content into memory

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache

I am using **Redis** to read some key/value data (the data needs to be persistent although it will hardly change over time, there will be just an initial data upload). At the moment, I just installed Redis in my local environment to implement the logic to read the data.

However, I also need to think of what will Redis look like when deploying the application. Since the application will be deployed to AWS, I guess that I will need to use **ElastiCache**. But obviously, since ElastiCache is another web service within the AWS ecosystem, the queries on Redis will need to travel over the wire as opposed to the situation in my Dev environment where Redis content is in memory.

Does this make sense? Should I modify the application to make an initial loading of Redis data into an in-memory variable in order to ensure that the data is always read from memory in all the environments?

Answer (score 0):

No, that would just be an overkill.
Redis works pretty fast, and the only overhead you will have as compared to a `localhost` instance will be the network latency.
**If you use the ElasticCache in same zone as your AWS deployment, you will be good to go and performant**. 
There is no need to copy that data to local memory, that would add to issues like consistency of cached data and two level invalidations.